# Why is the voltage near the load of a circuit less than that of the battery?

Tags: circuit-design

I made a circuit in a simulator with a 9V battery, a bulb and a voltmeter across the bulb.

The voltmeter showa a reading of 8.72V.

Why?

Comment: Read up on battery chemistry. Battery voltage can and does vary significantly from the label. Some rechargeable chemistries have a nominal charged voltage of about 8.4 V. And voltage will drop with load. But all you posted is an image. Did you actually measure a real one? Results will vary with different battery types and loads.

Comment: Cz batteries have internal resistance.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that whatever simulator you're using¹ is simulating the internal resistance of the battery. 9 V batteries are not capable of providing much current; their internal resistance is quite high, so loading them down even a little big causes the voltage to drop.

Note that this means the voltage at the load is *not* lower than the voltage at the battery; the voltage at the battery terminals will also be the same 8.49 V that you're seeing at the lamp terminals. This is purely an effect of the battery itself that you're seeing, and not an effect of any other part of the circuit.

In a real circuit, the voltage at the lamps would be reduced slightly by the resistance of the wires, but simulators rarely if ever include this resistance², and yours doesn't appear to (if it did, and the resistance was enough to affect anything, the voltage measured at the two lamps would be different).

---

<sub>¹ At the time this answer was posted, the question included an image of a simulator showing the lowered voltage. This has since been removed, but the answer stands for a real circuit as well.</sub>

<sub>² Wire resistance depends on many factors about the wire that it would be tedious to have to enter for every wire, and in most cases it's so small it doesn't affect the circuit at all. If it *was* necessary to include, you could add a resistor in series to represent it; it would most likely have a value of less than a milliohm.</sub>

Comment: The question still says the circuit is being examined in a simulator, so it's still a good answer.

Comment: The image is still available here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeKfn.png

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. OP's original simulation image.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuj7p1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Schematic showing battery's internal resistance.*

Even a small internal resistance value can cause a significant voltage drop at the battery terminals when high enough current is drawn. Figure 2 shows similar results to your simulation when the internal resistance is set to 1 Ω for a 50 Ω load (two 100 Ω resistors in parallel).

The internal resistance of a battery increases as it discharges. This will generally make the terminal voltage worse as the battery is depleted.

The good thing about all this is that your simulator seems to be taking the battery's internal resistance into account and giving a reasonably accurate simulation.

Answer (score 0):

A 9 V battery does not provide 9 V exactly. It's voltage decreases when it is discharged. It's ususally made up of 6 alkaline cells in series which only have a *nominal* voltage of 1.5 V each.